# Derivatives and double roots in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: derivatives, algebraic-number-theory, factoring

Is there a notion of double roots of polynomials in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$? By that I mean if for a polynomial $P(x)$ we have that $p^n|P(a) $ and $p^n|P'(a)$, then $(x-a)^2$ divides $P(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

To be specific, I wanted to show that if a prime power $>3$ divides $(n^2+n+1)^2$ for $6|n-1$, then it divides $(n+1)^{n+1}-n^n$.

I wanted to prove it by showing that if a prime power $p^n$ divides $n^2+n+1$, then $n$ is a double root of $(x+1)^{n+1}-x^n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.

I tried this because if we have what I claim, then since $6|n-1$, we have that $(x+1)^{n+1}-x^n=(x^2+x+1)Q(x)$ for some $Q(x)$ belonging to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, and the fact that $(x-n)^2 $ cannot divide $x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, we would have that due to the double root, $p^n|Q(n)$, which would give the desired.

Comment: Please don't [delete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474455/double-roots-in-mathbbz-pn-mathbbzx) and repost. Rather edit your post.

Comment: Extremely sorry,I am new to the website,can u please help with the above problem.

Comment: I have a counterexample. Take $n=7$. Then $3^2$ divides $(n^2+n+1)^2$, but $3^2$ doesn't divide $(n+1)^{n+1}-n^n$. Ah, sorry, you need $p>3$, I think.

Comment: Yes,p is greater than 3,I verified with wolfram and this seems correct,but does the method I stated in the above post work?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes I mean P(x) is a polynomial with integer coefficients as evident from my attempt at using it (with $(x+1)^{n+1}−x^n $ and the fact it has  $(x^2+x+1)$, as factor,I was trying to use that,because if what I use is true about the double root ,then we would be done).Also,@above a friend of mine on discord gave me this problem and asked me to prove it,could you tell me which competition problem is this?

Comment: Please do not deface your post after it's been answered. The context provided by the text you're trying to remove is relevant to the post and leaving it in improves its quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ and $f(a)\equiv f'(a)\equiv  0\bmod p^k$ then let $g(x) = f(x+a)=\sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n$ so that $c_0= f(a)\equiv 0 \bmod p^k,c_1= f'(a)\equiv 0\bmod p^k$ ie. $g(x)=x^2 h(x)+p^k j(x)$ with $j\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ and $f(x)=(x-a)^2 h(x-a)+p^k j(x-a)$.

Comment: Can u please elaborate a bit,is this a counterexample ?I believe this shows what I asked for but I am not sure.Someone please confirm.

Comment: Which part is unclear to you

Comment: Like this does prove that if p^k|P(a) and P'(a),then (x-a)^2 divides P in Z/p^nZ[X],can u just confirm please ,thanks!

Comment: Also then the conclusion I made in the above post is correct?

Comment: Which part is unclear in my answer?

Comment: yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Except for $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ it is not the same $n$ right